# Translate Videos from Google Drive without Uploading to our Server

Tags: google-drive-api, google-picker, virtual-server

I want to process the videos (which resides on google drive) for translation on my web application hosted on a virtual server?
is it possible to read the videos from google drive to be  processed on my virtual server without uploading the video to my server?
so that I could save the storage on my server, bandwitdh as well as the time required to upload the video.
For instance like we could read the videos or any other data directly on google drive in Google Colab without uploading.
is the same scenario possible with external web application like Google Colab.

Comment: depends on how you are processing it but i would bet the very least it has to be loaded into memory. which will require bandwidth to load it into memory on the server.